# How to set environment variables for gradle build from spring boot application.properties via command line?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

i want to be able to set environment variables during **gradle build**.

Below is the **application.properties** in spring boot

```
spring.datasource.url=${host}
spring.datasource.username=${username}
spring.datasource.password=${password}
```

whe trying to build a jar i want to be able to set
something like, **`gradle build -Dusername="user" -Dpassword="pwd" -Dhost="192.X.X.X"`**

How do i achieve in gradle?

Comment: did you figure this one out?